# 他很慢地走: why there is 地 if the adjective is monosyllabic?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles

I can't use 地 after the adjective if the adjective is monosyllabic (so 他慢地走 isn't acceptable). Then why in this sentence is there 地 after a monosyllabic adjective?

> 他很慢地走

Is it because I can use 地 if there is 很 before the adjective ?

Comment: the whole 状语，很慢 no longer is a monosyllabic adjective，in which case the following applies：实用现代汉语语法，５１２页：描写性的状语绝大多数后边可以用＂地＂１。形容词和形容词短语：加丽亚得意地说：＂我成功了！＂２。她大方地伸出手来同我握手。３。黄英激动地说：＂我太佩服你了！＂４。小红不高兴的走了。５。这时他很客气地提出三点要求。６。全会场都在静静地等待着。７。她一只手拿着筷子，两眼直瞪瞪地瞅着火苗。但单音节形容词后一般不用＂地＂。如＂他看着我傻笑＂。

Answer (score 5):

> I can't use 地 after the adjective if the adjective is monosyllabic

This is not a grammatical rule. This is an idiomatic rule and mostly for prosody concerns.

All the following expressions are grammatically correct. Only some sounds more natural than the others:

- 他慢地走 <- sounds unnatural
- 他很慢地走 <- sounds fine but not idiomatic
- 他慢慢地走 <- sounds fine and idiomatic

Answer (score -2):

Darlin' who is teaching you this stuff? I hope you are not paying too much!

You can say: 她很慢地走。or 她慢慢地走。

Better might be: 她在很慢地走。 or 她走得很慢。

Goodnight, Miss Chestnut!

Comment: Don't say `慢地走`...

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, missed a 慢, was a bit drunk last night!