# Why is 的 needed in 二来是更深度的了解中国文化?

Tags: grammar, word

In the following sentence:

> 这次来中国，一来是提高中文水平，二来是更深度**的**了解中国文化。

The meaning should be something like the follows:

> The reason I came to China this time is, for one reason in order to raise my Chinese proficiency, and for another to understand the Chinese culture more deeply.

I also understand that 地 can be used to make the adjective work as an adverb. But this is 的, not 地.

If I break down the components:

- 更深度的 - adverb?
- 了解 - verb
- 中国文化 - object

I also understand 的 can make the adjective to a noun phrase, but in that case, it becomes a form of O-V-O, which doesn't make sense.

So why is 的 needed in the sentence above and how does it work there?

Comment: I think 地 should be used instead, because 了解 is a verb here. 了解 could be used as noun too, that might be the root of the error.

Comment: @songyuanyao Then it is a typo? The sentence comes from [the popular Chinese grammar wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Stating_two_or_more_reasons_with_%22yilai...erlai%22), FYI.

Comment: Well, I asked google.com and it gives 5 results for "更深度地了解中国文化" and 4 results for "更深度的了解中国文化". :)

Comment: the problem seems to be that 深度 is a noun, while adjectives functioning as adverbs of course require 地，similarly 更 in the present case seems to modify a noun, whereas it usually modifies (stands before) an adjective or verb；it seems possible to replace 深度  by the adjective 深, jukuu has 2 samples with  更深地了解, one with  更深地理解

Comment: It is a 语病 https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%AF%AD%E7%97%85

Comment: From the link above: 如：修饰语语序不当（修饰应回归在自己修饰的中心语前面）——这是有效**的**治疗高血压的方法。（“有效的”属性质的定语要靠近中心语）

Comment: 更深度的 and 更深度地 both aren't exactly grammatically correct. It should really be 更有深度地 but the meaning does get across.

Comment: @TangHo What does this mean? (in your second comment)

Comment: 这是有效(的)治疗高血压方法 --> 这是有效治疗高血压(的)方法 ; 更深度(的)了解中国文化--> 更深度了解中国(的)文化

Comment: I would replace "更深度的" with "更深入地" which sounds more natural and appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say in modern Chinese, 的 is often used to replace 地 in this kind of sentences.

Both 深度的了解中国文化 and 深度地了解中国文化 are acceptable.

I personally prefer 深度的了解中国文化.

You could refer to the definition 5 for 的 in [this dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/js/7684.htm).

This example demonstrates my point to your [previous question 26301](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26301/can-all-adjectives-be-transformed-into-adverbs-with-%E5%9C%B0/26303#26303).

This is the screenshot from the dictionary of my handset, which defines it clearly.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the linked dictionary, what does 2 in “地2” mean?

Comment: It means it is the same as in the definition 2 of 地, referring to this link for  结构助词，用在词或词组之后表示修饰后面的谓语：慢慢～走。 http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/5730.htm

Comment: “的” - 副词尾， 同“地2”； 地： 助词。。。。You know the difference between 副词 and 助词 right?!

Comment: @Kevman: you should also aware of the difference between 副词尾 and 副词. 副词尾 means it is used at the end of adv, for example 慢慢地， 慢慢 is adv and 地 is at the end of it.

Comment: And if it isn't quite clear, see this one too.  "同“地”(de)。用在状语后,表示状语和中心词之间的修饰关系 " http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/14239.html

Comment: I also upload the screenshot from my handset dictionary.

Comment: I understand it is used misused frequently now (I asked it to my Chinese friend just now) but do you "personally prefer 深度的了解中国文化"?

Comment: @Blaszard.  When I was in element school and junior middle school, I was educated the difference between 的 and 地. I know it very well!  But when I was in High middle school, my Chinese literature teacher told us now 的 and 地 are interchangeable for this usage, and you won't be wrong even you use it in any type of exams. So, this usage has been authorized officially. That's why you would see the definition from any type of modern dictionaries, saying 的 can be used to replace 地 for this usage.

Comment: May I ask which city you grew up in and what generation you are from (it’s OK if you don’t like)? Does it differ by regions and generation?

Comment: @Blaszard, However, I checked back my literature teacher in junior middle school yesterday. She said there had been time they taught the students they are interchangeable. But now they switched back to the old rule for 的 and 地，because teachers feel the students can not feel the differences between 的 and 地 in other usages.

Comment: @Blaszard, now, for you, I think you can stick to that old rule, but you shouldn't be surprised if you see others use it in the "wrong" way.

Comment: @Blaszard, The reason why I am in favor of 的 is: 1. since their pronunciations are exactly the same, why do we need to redundantly use two characters to serve the same purpose only in written. 2. Language is not about the grammar, but conventions. if it's been widely used(maybe mistakenly in grammar), why do you need to keep saying it's "a common mistake"? I have experienced this kind of change a lot in our official dictionary - originally ungrammatical to officially approved.

Comment: @Blaszard, I don't think it's a matter of region and generation. It's a matter that this is going to be approved officially or not.

Answer (score 1):

The author used "的" incorrectly.

Obviously should use"地".